# How can I use gather function to manipulate my data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I Have a data frame as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(Name = c("a","c","d","b","f","g","h"), group = c(2,1,2,3,1,3,1))

  Name group
   a     2 
   c     1
   d     2
   b     3
   f     1
   g     3
   h     1
```

I would like to use gather function from tidyverse package to reshape my data frame to the following format.

```
  group  Name total
    1   c,f,h   3
    2    a,d    2
    3    b,h    2
```

Do you know how can I do this?

Thanks,

Comment: To understand gather, you can also have a look at [tidyexplain](https://github.com/gadenbuie/tidyexplain/tree/pkg#gather)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'group' and `paste` the elements of 'Name' with `toString`, while getting the total number of elements with `n()`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(Name = toString(Name), total = n())
```